# How do I access variables from a custom class?

Tags: ios

Here is how it looks in the storyboard :

[image]

CustomTabBarController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController<UITabBarDelegate>
@property NSUInteger tabIndex;
@property NSUInteger pageIndex;
@end
```

I have variables stored in CustomTabBarController how can I access them in the RootViewController?

Comment: You can pass desired variables from CustomTabBar to RootViewController to use it when you create your RootViewController.

Comment: If you are likely to use these values throughout the app it might be worth splitting them out into a Singleton http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: I have seen the name singleton a lot of times I will certainly take a look thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Pre-condition:* your **property need to be public** in the `CustomTabBarController` interface (`CustomTabBarController.h`):

```
@interface CustomTabBarController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Class *object;

@end
```

You can access the property by **any controller in your tabBarController**:

```
((CustomTabBarController *)self.tabBarController).object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the root view controller from **viewControllers** property of the tab bar controller. You need to type cast it to the appropriate class.For example

```
static NSString *const TabIdentifier = TAB_IDENTIFIER;
UITabBarController *tabBarController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:TabIdentifier];
[(ViewController *)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setData:mdata];
```